# How to get only image src attribute from rails image_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a scenario in which I only need the `src` attribute generated by `image_tag`.

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("diane.png")
```

gives back

```
<img src=\"/assets/diane-d88012c06a724682b02dfbd9224dbaac15872a3.png\" alt=\"Diane\" />
```

I only need the string in the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [image_path](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path):

```
 ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path("diane.png")
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks